# Gatling : Extension method to Simulation

Tags: scala, gatling

Trying to run multiple simulations in Gatling, but there is a process that I want to do before each Simulation is run. Is there an extension method while extending Simulation that I can hook onto so that all the classes that extends Simulation will run this piece of code?

```
class CreateAddressSimulation extends Simulation {
      // Create address code
}

class ReadAddressSimulation extends Simulation {
     // Read address code
}
```

Comment: so are you looking to 'seed' some data for your test run?

Comment: used a before hook in each of the simulation class

Answer (score 0):

You need resolve via several exec()

```
.exec(createAddress)
.exec(readAddress)
```